# SD card writing failure

Tags: c++

I have a friend whose Adruino code won't write to an SD card and was looking for some help. Here's the code, thanks so much! If you can find any issues please let me know about them.

```
/* FSR testing sketch, log data to SD card 

Connect one end of FSR to power, the other end to Analog 0.
Then connect one end of a 10K resistor from Analog 0 to ground 

For more information see www.ladyada.net/learn/sensors/fsr.html */

int fsrPin = 0;                 // the FSR and 10K pulldown are connected to a0
int fsrReading = 0;             // the analog reading from the FSR resistor divider
int fsrVoltage = 0;             // the analog reading converted to voltage
unsigned long fsrResistance;    // The voltage converted to resistance, can be very big so make "long"
unsigned long fsrConductance;
long fsrForce;                  // Finally, the resistance converted to force

#include <SD.h>                 //Load SD card library
#include<SPI.h>                 //Load SPI Library

#include "Wire.h"               // imports the wire library for talking over I2C
long Adafruit_P1075A = fsrForce;        // create sensor object called fsrForce

int chipSelect = 4;             //chipSelect pin for the SD card Reader
File fsrForceData;              //Data object you will write your sensor data to

void setup ( void )
{

// fsrForce.begin();   //initialize pressure sensor fsrForce
    Serial.begin ( 9600 );      // We'll send debugging information via the Serial monitor

    pinMode ( 10, OUTPUT );     //Must declare 10 an output and reserve it
    SD.begin ( 4 );             //Initialize the SD card reader
}

void loop ( void )
{
    fsrReading = analogRead ( fsrPin );
    Serial.print ( "Analog reading = " );
    Serial.println ( fsrReading );

    // analog voltage reading ranges from about 0 to 1023 which maps to 0V to 5V (= 5000mV)
    fsrVoltage = map ( fsrReading, 0, 1023, 0, 5000 );
    Serial.print ( "Voltage reading in mV = " );
    Serial.println ( fsrVoltage );

    if ( fsrVoltage == 0 )
    {
        Serial.println ( "No pressure" );
    }
    else
    {
        // The voltage = Vcc * R / (R + FSR) where R = 10K and Vcc = 5V
        // so FSR = ((Vcc - V) * R) / V        yay math!
        fsrResistance = 5000 - fsrVoltage;      // fsrVoltage is in millivolts so 5V = 5000mV
        fsrResistance *= 10000; // 10K resistor
        fsrResistance /= fsrVoltage;
        Serial.print ( "FSR resistance in ohms = " );
        Serial.println ( fsrResistance );

        fsrConductance = 1000000;       // we measure in micromhos so 
        fsrConductance /= fsrResistance;
        Serial.print ( "Conductance in microMhos: " );
        Serial.println ( fsrConductance );
    }
    // Use the two FSR guide graphs to approximate the force
    if ( fsrConductance <= 1000 )
    {
        fsrForce = fsrConductance / 80;
        Serial.print ( "Force in Newtons: " );
        Serial.println ( fsrForce );
    }
    else
    {
        fsrForce = fsrConductance - 1000;
        fsrForce /= 30;
        Serial.print ( "Force in Newtons: " );
        Serial.println ( fsrForce );
    }
    {
        //   pressure=fsrForce.readPressure(); //Read Pressure

        fsrForceData = SD.open ( "PTData.txt", FILE_WRITE );
        if ( fsrForceData )
        {
            fsrForceData.print ( "The Force is: " );
            fsrForceData.print ( fsrForce );
            fsrForceData.println ( " N." );
            fsrForceData.println ( "" );
            delay ( 250 );      //Pause between readings.

            fsrForceData.println ( "--------------------" );
            delay ( 1000 );

            fsrForceData.close (  );    //close the file
        }
    }
}
```

This says I need more detail to post but its pretty self explanatory. Once again, any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what the problem is and what you have already tried. Is the read-only switch on the SD card enabled? Does the file get created but no data is written? It's hard to diagnose the problem without knowing any of the symptoms!

Comment: This might be better posted to https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: If your SD Card formatted to a FAT16 or FAT32 file system?  Does it have free-space?  Do you get any file created? Is the SD Card wired to the PIN being used (`4`)? It's only necessary to include the last block of code, it's the only part dealing with the SD Card.